# How do multiple wifi antennas work?

Tags: wireless-networking

I am using a DIR-855, and have been tinkering with the antennas. I have found the following:

There are 3 antenna slots, lets call them A, B and C

when B, C are connected, but A is disconnected, wireless signal drops to almost nothing

when A is connected alone, wireless signal is good

Does this mean that the router is only using antenna A?

I want to replace the antennas with high-gain ones for a better signal, hence the toying around. currently have 1 8db antenna in addition to the stock ones.

Comment: More info ion MIMO wireless....http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIMO

Answer (score 3):

At least in the case of two antenna routers, one is used for send, one is used for receive.  It sounds like in this case A is used for sending.  Since it's a dual-band router, B or C may be for the other band.

Comment: Does this mean that its necessary to replace both send and receive antennas to have better performance? The stock antennas are dual 2.4/5Ghz antennas. Its abit wierd if only one was used for 5Ghz

Comment: Some software will let you configure which antenna is used.  If both ends use directional antennas to transmit the receive antennas should be fine.  You might get some more range with high-gain directional antennas on the receive side.